# Confusion regarding PRESET and not(PRESET)

Tags: flipflop

After watching the video explanation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXoQ4WAQ0qk) regarding PRESET and CLEAR . I have made following conclusions .

Considering **Active Low / bubbled** case as shown below image

[image]

- Whenever CLEAR is 0 implies output Q is  0
- Whenever PRESET is 0 implies output Q is  1

So Is  it correct to conclude that

- Whenver not(PRESET) is 1 implies output Q is 0
- Whenever not(CLEAR) is 1 implies output Q is  1

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Or in other words is it correct to conclude

- PRESET  is 0 implies output Q is 1 , not(PRESET) is not(0) i.e 1(WHENEVER ACTIVE LOW/BUBBLED)
- not(PRESET)  is 0 implies PRESET is not(0) i.e 1 , Q is 1 (WHENEVER ACTIVE HIGH/not BUBBLED)

Answer (score 1):

PRESET and CLEAR work like this:

If PRESET is LOW and CLEAR is HIGH, Q is HIGH regardless of what happens on J,K, and CLK.

IF PRESET is HIGH and CLEAR is LOW, Q is LOW regardless of what happens on J,K, and CLK.

IF PRESET is LOW and CLEAR is LOW, Q is undefined. (The two inputs are fighting each other.)

IF PRESET is HIGH and CLEAR is HIGH, the rules concerning the J,K and CLK inputs for a JK flip-flop apply.

In other words, if neither PRESET nor CLEAR is asserted, the flip-flop operates normally, However, asserting either will override the state of the flip-flop. And if both are asserted, the result is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

**Set** will set the Q output HIGH

**Reset** will reset the Q output LOW

Set, Reset means that it is activated by a HIGH (normally input is pulled LOW)

Not Set, Not Reset means that it is activated by a LOW (normally input is pulled HIGH)